# Count pairs A-B and B-A with a third argument

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a little table with 3 column :

```
+---------------------------+
| col 1 | col2  | col 3     |
+---------------------------+
|  A    | B     |    10     |
|  A    | B     |    20     |
|  B    | A     |    20     |
|  B    | C     |    10     |
|  B    | C     |    20     |
|  A    | C     |    10     |
|  C    | A     |    10     |
```

What I want to to is to count the number of different value of the column 3 each couple (col 1, col 2) gets. 
My problem is I can't get to handle the doublon as (A,B) is the same as (B,A).

Here is the result I try to get :

```
+------------------------+
| col 1 | col 2 | count()|
+------------------------+
|  A    |  B    |  2     |  // OR BA : 2 
|  B    |  C    |  2     |  // OR CB : 2 
|  A    |  C    |  1     |  // OR CA : 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)` and `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(col1, col2) as col1, greatest(col1, col2) as col2
       count(distinct col3) as cnt
from t
group by least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2);
```

Comment: thx a lot it worked, i'm going to check the doc of least and greatest !